# Oracle ADF Hosting Pricing

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I found it easier (because I have been working on it) to create web applications using Oracle ADF and related tools but I am not sure of how much it will cost.
 I am no entrepreneur or organization, I am just a developer but I had an idea of developing web application (a typical data input, store and report like) for which Oracle ADF will ease my development. The Oracle's pricing list looks complicated. My total operational budget(including hosting, and licenses)  is around $50-$100 per month (which I know is very less, but GAE or AWS comes around this budget). I am looking at a small userbase here mayB grow slowly.
Thanks

Comment: see https://community.oracle.com/thread/3556498?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaking is the cheapest WebLogic Server license +- 20.000 dollar per CPU.

You can use ADF Essentials + GlassFish. Those are both free to use, the downside is that ADF Essentials doesn't support out of the box security.

Comment: Thanks, Any hosting sites that I can use for production instance ?

Comment: @IdeaInside I don't have any practical experience with that. But some VPS hostings sites offer an glassfish server. Just google 'VPS Glassfish' for references.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does have a cloud offering where you pay per month and it can run ADF apps on WebLogic - see - https://cloud.oracle.com/mycloud/f?p=service:java_pricing:0:::::

But given the amount you had in mind you might want to look into the GlassFish+ADF Essentials option. http://multikoop.blogspot.com/2012/09/adf-essentials-in-redhat-cloud.html